# Best solution for "No Scheme" issue in Xcode 4 after defected merging git branches

Tags: ios, git, xcode4, merge

Got the "No Scheme" issue after merging the conflict issue

> Auto-merging SampleProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
>   CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in SampleProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
>   Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Definitely I took some defected operations when merging the conflicts. 
The question is that does there has any best solution to fix the "No Scheme" issue in this kind of case.

Answer (score 37):

When Schemes shows "**No Scheme**" option, Click on

**`No Scheme` -> `Manage Scheme` -> then click the button `Autocreate Schemes Now`**

Answer (score 4):

I found the top rated answer didn't work for me so thought I would post my usual approach here - as I just had to solve this problem:

We know the problem - the error is actually quite clear on this issue:

> Auto-merging SampleProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj CONFLICT
>   (content): Merge conflict in SampleProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
>   Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

We have a conflict in the **project.pbxproj** file.

If it said "Conflict in appDelegate.h" we'd know exactly what to do but the fact the project won't compile seems to be more worrying than a normal conflict - which is what this actually is.

So how do we go about fixing this conflict?

1. First navigate to your project file
2. Right click the xcodeproj file
3. Click Show Package Contents

[image]

4. Double click the project.pbxproj file (that's the the one mentioned in the conflict error)

[image]

5. Finally resolve the conflicts as you would normally do. 
   This requires a little bit of thought - it is worth reading and trying to understand approximately what is happening. Usually though it is quite straight forward to see what needs to be kept:

[image]

Above is an example of how the conflicts will look.

Once you have found all the conflicts in this file just save and reload the project. The scheme should be back and the project working.

**Note:** As mentioned above some thought is required when resolving the conflicts. Usually they will be very easy (just remove the conflict lines) but sometimes you will need to fix a little bit of code. If you see the example below - the file had been corrupted and needed to be fixed:

[image]

The fix required in this example was:

```
        path = DetailModels;
        sourceTree = "<group>";
    };
```

This code needed to be added and could be worked out from the code in the above areas.

Comment: Thank you! `sourceTree = "<group>";` & `};` in the end of group were the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue.  Closed my projects, quit then re-opened XCode and my schemes were back.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same issue.
After some trials, I Opened the Xcode and went to the issue navigator and opened the conflicted files as Source Code, then started to search by keyword `<<<<<<< HEAD` then started to fix the conflicts.
After that the Target appeared :)

Answer (score 1):

**In Xcode 12.1 and swift 5**

**Following Things working for me**

1-Click on No Scheme

2- Click on Manage Scheme

3- Click on Autocreate Schemes Now
[image]

Comment: OP is asking about Xcode 4... note that question is 9 years old.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16373744/2227743).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved my "No Scheme" dilemma. After several hours of trial and error, I tried to delete the xcode.workspace that didn't hav schemes and cd to the folder where the workspace was just deleted from, than I ran pod install to re-download the workspace. And then all my projects and folder showed up.

It was also important to navigate to target->build settings and set the FrameWork Search Paths for debug and release to ($inherited) and $(SRCROOT) before deleting the workspace.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .xworkspace file, then re-run pod install. You'll get back your scheme.

Comment: This answer should not get downvoted. "Autocreate schemes now" did nothing for me, but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I used git mergetool to fix my conflicts. I forgot to close all the tabs of filemerge and was trying to open my workspace. So, that was the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting my entire project and reinstalling pod files resolved the issue (None of the above worked).